# Touchphase.Ended does not run

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to give force to a `rigidbody` object by touch and dragging away from it and then releasing the touch. But the `Touchphase.End` just doesn't run. I can't find the answer to this problem. I get input from one touch until the touch releases, on releasing the touch the distance between the starting and final position is calculated and a similar force is applied on the `rigidbody` to make it move. The object on which the code is attached is the same object which needs to move.

```
   // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Update the Text on the screen depending on current TouchPhase, and the current direction vector

        // Track a single touch as a direction control.
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {

                Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                _touchPosWorld =
                    Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position); //get the position where the screen was touched

                RaycastHit2D hitInformation = Physics2D.Raycast(_touchPosWorld, Vector2.zero);
                FirstTouch = (hitInformation.collider.CompareTag("ball"));


                if (FirstTouch || IsInTouch)
                {
                    // Handle finger movements based on TouchPhase
                    switch (touch.phase)
                    {
                        //When a touch has first been detected, change the message and record the starting position
                        case TouchPhase.Began:
                            // Record initial touch position.

                            IsInTouch = true;
                            _startPos = touch.position;
                            GameManager.GetInstance().ChangeAccordinglyText.text = "clicked Inside";//test text


                            //Movement started
                            break;

                        //Determine if the touch is a moving touch
                        case TouchPhase.Moved:
                            // Determine direction by comparing the current touch position with the initial one
                            _direction = touch.position - _startPos;

                            GameManager.GetInstance().ChangeAccordinglyText.text = "MovingTouch to " + touch.position; //test text 


                            //moving
                            break;

                        case TouchPhase.Ended:
                            // Report that the touch has ended when it ends
                            //end of movement of touch

                            GameManager.GetInstance().EndedText.text = "EndOfTouch";

                            float force = 0;
                            force = _direction.x > _direction.y ? _direction.x : _direction.y;
                            _rigidbody.AddForce(_direction * force);
                            FirstTouch = false;
                            IsInTouch = false;
                            break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you seem to be relying on mouse button and touch?

Comment: its same for mobile isnt it ? i just kept the if(input.getMouseButton(0)) clause to stop it from going full error crazy if opened on editor.  Because editor cannt get touch count or id

Answer (score 0):

Your `TouchPhase.End` will never be reached since in the moment you release the touch also `GetMouseButton(0)` will be **`false`** and thus the entire block skipped!

---

To avoid the errors you are talking about before trying to access a certain touch, first check if there is any touch to access using [`Input.touchCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touchCount.html)

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

    // ...
}
```

---

In general for development you should rather check for e.g. [`Input.touchSupported`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touchSupported.html) and implement an alternative mouse system for simulating the touches

```
if(Input.touchSupported)
{
    /* Implement touches */ 
    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        // ...
    }
} 

// Optional
else 
{ 
    /* alternative mouse implementation for development */
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        // simulates touch begin
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        // simulates touch moved
    }

    // I've seen in strange occasions that down and up might get called within one frame
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        // simulates touch end
    }
}
```